# Showing that the union of transitive relations need not be transitive.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, relations

I have a counterexample of the following statement but I am not sure if it is correct:

> Suppose $R_1$ and $R_2$ are relations on A. If $R_1$ and $R_2$ are transitive, then $R_1 \cup R_2$ is transitive. Prove or provide a counterexample.

To me, this is of the form:

If:

$$((x,y)\in R_1 \land (y,z) \in R_1 \implies (x,z)\in R_1) \land ((x,y)\in R_2 \land (y,z) \in R_2 \implies (x,z)\in R_2) $$

Then:

$$ ((x,y)\in R_1 \lor (x,y) \in R_2) \land ((y,z)\in R_1 \lor (y,z)\in R_2) \implies ((x,z)\in R_1 \lor (x,z)\in R_2)   $$

My counterexample:

\begin{align*}
A&=\{ 1,2,3\} \\
R_1&= \{(1,2)\} \\
R_2&= \{(2,3)\} 
\end{align*}

Then if we take $x=1,y=2,z=3$, it should yield the following:

If:

$$(\underbrace{(x,y)\in R_1 \land (y,z) \in R_1}_{\text{false}} \implies \underbrace{(x,z)\in R_1}_{\text{false}}) \land (\underbrace{(x,y)\in R_2 \land (y,z) \in R_2}_{\text{false}} \implies \underbrace{(x,z)\in R_2}_{\text{false}}) $$

Then:

$$ (\underbrace{(x,y)\in R_1 \lor (x,y) \in R_2)}_{\text{true}} \land (\underbrace{(y,z)\in R_1 \lor (y,z)\in R_2)}_{\text{true}} \implies (\underbrace{(x,z)\in R_1 \lor (x,z)\in R_2}_{\text{false}})   $$

I know it's a mess, but it's the best I can do to illustrate my idea clearly. Could anyone please help? Thank you so much!

Comment: This looks correct to me, if a bit overly formalized. It's clear that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are vacuously transitive and their union is not transitive because $(1,3) \notin R_1 \cup R_2$.

Comment: @aduh Thank you! Yes being too formal is a problem of mine, but I am just not sure how to tone it down without not being able to express my idea...
Actually the reason I asked was because another solution I saw was not vacuous, i.e. both $R_1$ and $R_2$ are transitive in an actual sense, so it's not immediately clear me how this is vacuously transitive.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, your counterexample is perfectly valid, though you seem to overthink a bit. All you need to note are the following:

- $R_1,R_2$ are both singletons
- $R_1$ is transitive since $(1,2),(1,2) \in R_1$ and $(1,2) \in R_1$
- $R_2$ is transitive since $(2,3),(2,3) \in R_2$ and $(2,3) \in R_2$
- $R_1 \cup R_2$ is not transitive since $(1,2),(2,3) \in R_1 \cup R_2$ but $(1,2) \not \in R_1 \cup R_2$

Thus the union of transitive relations is not necessarily transitive. (In fact, even if $R_1,R_2$ are equivalence relations, their union still need not be one, and need not even be transitive, as you can see explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952330/prove-or-disprove-if-r-and-s-are-two-equivalence-relations-on-a-set-a-the).)

---

*Mostly just posting this to get this out of the unanswered queue. Posting as Community Wiki in particular since I have nothing further to add.*