# What is the $\textit{intuition}$ behind the union of two equivalences relations on a set $A$ not being itself an equivalence relation.

Tags: relations, intuition, equivalence-relations

*Prove or disprove*: If $R$ and $S$ are two equivalence relations on a set $A$, the $R \cup S$ is also an equivalence relation on $A$.

This statement has been *disproven* [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952330/prove-or-disprove-if-r-and-s-are-two-equivalence-relations-on-a-set-a-the). In addition, we know that $R \cap S$ *is* indeed an equivalence relation through simply mathematical reasoning. My question is: Is there any intuition for why $R\cup S$ would not itself be an equivalence relation as well? If there is, then what is the intuition?

This question came to mind after seeing that $R\cap S$ is and equivalence relation on $A$ but not $R \cup S$.

Any help in the intuition part is great! Thanks!

Comment: Well, why should it be?  You could have $a\sim_1 b$ and $b\sim_2 c$ but $a\not \sim_i c$ for $i\in \{1,2\}$.

Comment: That makes sense! I like the succinctness! @lulu

Comment: To make a concrete example out of that, consider congruences $\mod 2$ and $\mod 3$.    We have $2\equiv 4 \pmod 2$ and $4\equiv 7\pmod 3$ but $2\not \equiv 7 \pmod 2$ and $2\not \equiv 7 \pmod 3$.